# Footable Filtering Rows - Getting Count of Results

Tags: footable

Is there a way to get the footable results of the filter function, such as number of rows showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question a few weeks ago. You can accomplish the following by doing this:

```
$('.footable tbody tr:not(.footable-filtered)').length
```

Comment: Note that if you don't want to select tr's outside of the footable, you can add in the child selector ">": $('.footable>tbody>tr:not(.footable-filtered)').length

Comment: The above does not work with the current version of Footable any more - FooTable seems to remove everything not visible (also for pagination) from the DOM.